# Create a new category column based on current one on large scale

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I want to ask an issue about creating a new category on a relatively large scale.

I'm doing data cleaning with NYPD complaint data and I like to assign each crime event (row) with a new type of crime. I plan to minimize the amount of unique type of crime from originally 59 to only 20, and I would do this by my own understanding (e.g. include 'Assault 2' & 'Offense' into 'Assault'). I'm thinking of using a dictionary to map into a new column in the data frame but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this since I have to assign multiple values into one new value (e.g. I'm not sure if I could use the dictionary like this {'Assault': ('Assault 2', 'Offense')} or list approach)

My question is what is the most efficient and pythonic way to do this work?
p.s. You could find the data on this site: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Complaint-Data-Current-Year-To-Date-/5uac-w243

Thanks!